# How to enable asynchronous indexing in production mode?

Tags: magento2, cron, index, production-mode

I want to enable the **[asynchronous indexing](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/performance-best-practices/configuration.html#asynchronous-order-data-processing)**, but the option is inside the Admin menu below, which is available just in developer mode.

**Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Grid Settings > Asynchronous indexing**

Do I need to put my store in developer mode, then change it to then return it to the production mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change it in production mode directly via terminal, then clean the cache.

```
bin/magento config:set dev/grid/async_indexing 1
bin/magento cache:clean
```